# How to export asciidoc to ODT or ODF using gradle?

Tags: gradle, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I was trying to export asciidoc document to ODT. I found unofficial backend implementation that does the work: https://github.com/dagwieers/asciidoc-odf. My question is: how can install and use this backend using gradle? Is it even possible? I have no idea how to start.

Here is my build.gradle that does it for PDF

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {  
      classpath 'org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-plugin:1.5.3'
      classpath 'org.asciidoctor:asciidoctorj-pdf:1.5.0-alpha.11'
      classpath 'org.asciidoctor:asciidoctorj-diagram:1.5.0'
   }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.asciidoctor.convert' version '1.5.3'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.asciidoctor.convert'


asciidoctorj {
    version = '1.5.4'
}

asciidoctor {
    backends 'pdf'
    requires 'asciidoctor-diagram'
    sourceDir = file('dok/')
    outputDir = file('build/')
    attributes \
        'buildDir': buildDir,
        'imagesdir': "$buildDir/images"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not something you want to hear. I think it is no possible to generate odf files with the asciidoctor-gradle-plugin. If you look at https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-examples which demonstrates examples for using gradle-plugin, I do not see an example for odf. :-(

It would be cool, if you could make a feature request at https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-plugin/issues and hopefully, someone will start.

Answer (score 2):

There's a thing to clarify first: the converter you mention (https://github.com/dagwieers/asciidoc-odf) is for the original Python implementation of the AsciiDoc language. The gradle plugin uses `Asciidoctor`, which is an alternative implementation done in Ruby, and if you ask me, the current reference standard.
Asciidoctor does not support ODF directly, but does support plugable converters and there's already an attempt (https://github.com/kubamarchwicki/asciidoctor-fodt), however, not stable it seems.
In those cases where no direct converter is available you can try some intermediate step like converting to doocbook and then from doocbook to the final format. Doing some googling I found a plugin from spring and apparently support to ODF from doocbook, but you'll need to test it and some features may be limited.

PS: I wanted to provide the links to the references but the ***** rep system prevents me from doing so.